# /var House Keeping

Tags: filesystems, logs, disk-usage

Does anyone have any general advice or links for doing some house keeping on the /var filesystem on Unix and Linux servers?

I have searched the issue quite a bit but can find no real concrete information on what I can/cannot do when I need to free up some space under /var (which happens a lot where I work).

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to minimize space on logdata is to use logrotate.

There is a good [tutorial on The GeekStuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)

Comment: Great link, much appreciated. What if I need more space after running logrotate, or what if logrotate is not available on the box in question (it might happen and as we generally can't install new packages aprticularly at the drop of hat it might not be feasible to rely on using it anyway).

Comment: Logrotate does not do any Voodoo. In general it moves the log away and restarts the service writing the logfiles. You can do that yourself without any program to install.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there isn't a universal guide for cleaning `/var` is that it highly depends on the system. **In short, `/var` is probably the most distribution-specific part of the filesystem hierarchy.** Apart from logs, typically managed by `logrotate` (see [ddeimeke's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43923/9382)), the following factors can significantly differ from installation to installation:

- the way your distribution handles package installation: how much management-related and build-time data does it store, and under what specific paths,
- the history of package installation, including installation attempts that failed for whatever reason,
- automatic clean-ups scheduled by default by your distro,
- the structure of `/var`: is it standardised by the distro (paths adjusted in the packaging process for each distributed package) or left the way each program has defined for itself,
- the specific software installed and used: each has its own settings that determine how much is stored, where, and quite often also for how long.

---

So, if you are looking for a generic way for doing clean-up, a there are generally two ways to go: search for distribution-specific information about managing `/var` or(and) manually determine, what part of the `/var` subtree is filled most often.

For the latter, you can use many tools, but probably the most generic is the `du` (*DiskUsage*) command-line program, together with **`xdiskusage`** for visualisation. If it's a headless server, you can store the output from `du` to a file, download it and run `xdiskusage` locally, supplying `du`'s output file as a parameter. The next step to implement some regular clean-up routines is determining, which program is responsible for which file(s) - some of this you can easily deduce, but in some cases you will have to use your distribution's package management utilities - they can very often tell you, which package a specific path belongs to.